# Validate that checkboxes are checked when not using model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox, validation

I have some checkboxes that are required to be checked before the user can go to the next page.  What is the best way to display a validation message?

View:

```
@Html.CheckBox("terms_eligibility")
@Html.CheckBox("terms_accurate")
@Html.CheckBox("terms_identity_release")
@Html.CheckBox("terms_score_release")
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Review(ReviewModel model)
{
    // Make sure all Terms & Conditions checkboxes are checked
    var termsEligibility = Request.Form.GetValues("terms_eligibility")[0];
    var termsAccurate = Request.Form.GetValues("terms_accurate")[0];
    var termsIdentityRelease = Request.Form.GetValues("terms_identity_release")[0];
    var termsScoreRelease = Request.Form.GetValues("terms_score_release")[0];

    if (termsEligibility == "true" && termsAccurate == "true" &&
        termsIdentityRelease == "true" && termsScoreRelease == "true")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("CheckOut","Financial");
    }

    return null;
}
```

---

EDIT,

I made the suggested changes.  Now how do i get the same page to display with error messages?

I changes the attributes in the model to this

```
 [RequiredToBeTrue(ErrorMessage = "*")]
```

here's the conroller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Review(ReviewModel model)
{


    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("CheckOut", "Financial");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Review");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you using a view model and a custom validation attribute:

```
public class RequiredToBeTrueAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return value != null && (bool)value;
    }
}
```

and the view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [RequiredToBeTrue]
    public bool TermsEligibility { get; set; }

    [RequiredToBeTrue]
    public bool TermsAccurate { get; set; }

    [RequiredToBeTrue]
    public bool TermsIdentityRelease { get; set; }

    [RequiredToBeTrue]
    public bool TermsScoreRelease { get; set; }

    ... some other properties that are used in your view
}
```

and the view will of course be strongly typed to the view model:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.TermsEligibility)   
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.TermsAccurate)   
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.TermsIdentityRelease)   
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.TermsScoreRelease)   
    ...
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and finally your controller action will take the view model as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Review(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // there were validation errors => redisplay the same view  
        // so that the user could fix them
        return View(model);
    }

    // at this stage we know that validation succeeded =>
    // we could proceed in processing the data and redirecting
    ...

    return RedirectToAction("CheckOut", "Financial");
}
```

Notice that things like `Request.Form.GetValues("terms_eligibility")[0];` and `termsEligibility == "true"` are really not the kind of code you would like to see in a properly written application.

Comment: thanks for the help. How do I display an error message if the validation fails.

Comment: That's what the `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)` helper does in my example. But if you want to do that for each individual checkbox you could also use the `ValidationMessageFor` helper next to each checkbox. For example: `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.TermsEligibility)`.

Comment: thanks I'm getting closer.  there two issues 1. When it fails validation the summary does show the errors, but the whol page diplays without any CSS styles..it's all text black and white.

Comment: 2. when it passes validation it hangs up on partial views on the same page that it has no problem with on the original GET for the page.

Comment: sorry #2 is incorrect, it's when I comment out the paritals and it fails validation that it displays the correct validation but there are no styles.   if it passess validation it works fine.

Comment: methods for partials had [HttpGet] attribute so they did not disply on post.  removed attribute and now they display.  Still no styles...displays page with no head section so no css...........

Comment: I figured out the style problems....all the navigation buttons are links that call javascript that load the page within a masterpage......